# Debug/Trace failing to write to Output windows in VSIX project

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, vsx, visual-studio-addins

Is there any reason, maybe a known bug or missing SDK that would cause debug and trace to stop working in the following environment:

I recently formated my workstation. Fresh install of VS2010 Ultimate in a solution I've been working with for a month. It contains an exe and a vsix as it's outputs. debug and trace work in the exe but when debugging the vsix nothing is written to the output window. I have the VS SDK installed. I've used Import/Export settings to reset the environment. I've disabled all extensions (from the extension manager). I also tried deleting the .suo files in the solution.

Comment: Resharper installs as an addon. It's has to be suspended from the tools->options->resharper menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you have Resharper installed by any chance?
2. When you break in the debugger and put System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners (or same for Trace) in the Watch window, what do you see?
3. Does doing System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener()) help?
4. Does adding a new [TextWriterTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) work?

Comment: Yes. Resharper is installed. Testing the rest now.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and it turned out Resharper was at fault. In general, you may just want to run your add-in in an Expiremental VS instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx) and remove Resharper from this instance - that will also do the trick.